# How do I access the hardware keys for the Samsung Galaxy Camera (EK-GC110)?

Tags: android, galaxy

I am writing a camera application and would like to be able to use the hardware capture, focus, and zoom rather than rely on on-screen buttons and views.

Comment: Override `onKeyDown()` and log what you get when you press them.

Comment: Good call. I was trying to do that in a fragment, but brought it up to the Activity and it works. Thanks!